# AngularJs Select menu using ng-repeat, first item should display differently

Tags: angularjs

Below code is fetching today's date and 7 more days e.g.  2016-02-01,  2016-02-02,  2016-02-03,  2016-02-04 etc.
but for today's date I do not want to display a date to user but word "Today" however, I want values in date format as I want to fill it into database while submitting form.

```
<select ng-model="item1" style=" width:100%; text-align:center;" ng-change="update()">
<option style="text-indent:30%" ng-repeat="item1 in IdeaMonth"  value="{{item1.one  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" >
{{item1.one  | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your custom filter, where you can use `moment` or the same angular js date filter to get the necessary value:

```
function compareDateParts(a, b)
{  
    var aMSec, bMSec;
    a = new Date(a);
    b = new Date(b);
    a.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    b.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    aMSec = a.getTime();
    bMSec = b.getTime();
    return aMSec  == bMSec  ? 0 : (aMSec  > bMSec  ? 1 : -1);
 }

angular.module('app').filter('customDate', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(date, format) {
         if(compareDateParts(date, new Date()) == 0) return "TODAY"
         return $filter('date')(date, format);
    };
}]);
```

Using `{{date | customDate: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}`

Comment: I need to use it with Ionicframework so , instead of angular.module('app') , should I use it into the relative controller, right ?

Comment: hm, actually it doesn't really matter, ionic uses the same angular but extends it with own servises, directives and so on. 
So you need to find in the project the file where the main module is registered like `angular.module('myApp', [...])` and use that module name with my solution

Comment: just wondering if there is any way , I simply create date format into js file and I need to print just array something like {{date}} instead of {{date | customDate: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}

Comment: sure, you can format dates in js.
`1) define the filter that I have described above;`
`2) inject $filter in the your conroller`
`3) use it there like $filter('customDate')(date, format);`